# How can i end SharePoint Designer workflow instance inside stage 1

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, sharepoint-designer-workflow

I have created one workflow in SharePoint designer which is pausing for 24 hrs and then again going back to "stage 1" to check **Ageing** field value. **How i can end the workflow instance** automatically if **Status** is "complete and published". Right now "End of workflow" is not coming inside "stage 1" when i am trying to add that inside status "complete and published" statement and workflow instance keeps on running although status is complete and published

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a if else condition in the Transition to stage, like this:

[image]